# Find out which apps are used by user via graph or fql

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there any possibility in FQL or Graph API to determine the ID of the apps someone is using? For example, to generate links to the FB App Fan Pages or showing a more detailed overview of the apps they is using? In the fql there is a table application, but good for what, if not for things like this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't.  There is an [application FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application/) that you could query but its indexed on app id or api key meaning you would have to specify one of those two fields in a where clause.  The only option would be to gather a collection of popular app ids and search for those.